# How can I reset a JsonReader instance instead of calling JToken.CreateReader?

Tags: c#, json, performance, json.net

I have a large JSON file that I'm deserializing using Newtonsoft.Json - and I'm experiencing performance issues, esp. regarding one specific detail:

While deserializing I need to use an IOC ("Inversion Of Control") Container to create the required instances.

Inspired by https://skrift.io/issues/bulletproof-interface-deserialization-in-jsonnet/ and other sources I implemented a custom `JsonConverter` that overrides `ReadJson`. The method signature includes `Type objectType`, but e.g. in the case of arrays, this may well only be some common interface and not a specific class type.

I serialized the data using the option `TypeNameHandling.Objects`, which includes a `"$type"` token for each class.

If I detect that the type is not sufficient, I do something like the following:

```
JObject o = JObject.Load(reader);

var typeName = o["$type"].ToString();

if (!tryGetBindingByName(typeName, out var detectedBinding))
    throw new SpecificBindingNotFoundBinderException(typeName, binding);

result = detectedBinding.DeserializeType;

//"reset" reader, because due to `JObject.Load(reader)` call above the reader's current position has changed
reader = o.CreateReader();
```

I think the performance critical part - esp. regarding heap allocations - is where I manually read the JSON object - and then the need to call `reader = o.CreateReader()`.

My question: can an existing `JTokenReader` be "reset" so that I can continue using it, instead of creating a new instance all the time?

Answer (score 1):

**No**.  Neither [`JTokenReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenReader.htm), nor the abstract [`JsonReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) on which it is based, provide a means to "reset" or go backward to an earlier point.  They are forward-only readers by design.

However, it sounds like the problem you are really trying to solve is just getting Json.Net to use your IOC container to create concrete instances of your classes in a performant manner.  For that, I think you might be using the wrong tool for the job.  Instead of a `JsonConverter`, try using a custom [`ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm).  You can supply your own `DefaultCreator` function to handle the instantiation for each Type, as shown below.

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonObjectContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        contract.DefaultCreator = () =>
        {
            // Change this to use your IOC container to create the instance.
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

            return instance;
        };
        return contract;
    }
}
```

To use the resolver, you just need to add it to the `JsonSerializerSettings` alongside the `TypeNameHandling.Objects` option you are already using:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(),
};
```

Here is a round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eHcLMb

---

If you also need to customize the type names that are written into the JSON, you can implement a custom [`SerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder.htm) to do that part.

Here is a contrived example to demonstrate the concept.  The `CustomSerializationBinder` below uses some hardcoded dictionaries to map some known types to an "alias", which is just a unique string I chose to represent that type.  The "known types" here are the same ones from the "Bulletproof Interface Deserialization in Json.Net" article you linked to in your question.  You can replace the dictionaries with whatever type lookup mechanism you require.  Note that I'm not using the `assemblyName` in the example below just to keep the JSON simple.

```
class CustomSerializationBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    Dictionary<string, Type> AliasToTypeMapping { get; set; }
    Dictionary<Type, string> TypeToAliasMapping { get; set; }

    public CustomSerializationBinder()
    {
        TypeToAliasMapping = new Dictionary<Type, string>
        {
            { typeof(Person), "Peep" },
            { typeof(Programming), "Coder" },
            { typeof(Writing), "Wordsmith" }
        };

        AliasToTypeMapping = new Dictionary<string, Type>(
            TypeToAliasMapping.Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<string, Type>(kvp.Value, kvp.Key))
        );
    }

    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        if (TypeToAliasMapping.TryGetValue(serializedType, out string alias))
        {
            assemblyName = null;  // I don't care about the assembly name for this example
            typeName = alias;
            return;
        };
        throw new Exception($"Type {serializedType.Name} is not mapped to an alias");
    }

    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if (AliasToTypeMapping.TryGetValue(typeName, out Type type))
        {
            return type;
        }
        throw new Exception("No type was found matching the alias {typeName}");
    }
}
```

To use the custom binder, you guessed it, just add it to the settings with the other stuff:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(),
    SerializationBinder = new CustomSerializationBinder()
};
```

Here is the same round-trip demo with the binder: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YC9IAT

Comment: Yes, I had a feeling I was trying to eat soup with a fork, but: using your solution on my project, `CreateObjectContract` is called for several types, but the `contract.DefaultCreator`resolve action is only called for the top-most instance/type. (I'm using `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(reader)` to deserialize from a stream.) Is there anything obvious I'm missing that you may be able to point me towards; if not, I'll try to break down my actual code into something reproducable. Thanks for the fiddle!

Comment: `CreateObjectContract` will only be called once per type, but the `DefaultCreator` should be called for every instance of each type.  Yes, if you could post a repro, that would really help.  I've tried to reproduce your problem using a stream and a class hierarchy implementing a common interface [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bBHCFZ), but it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Hey, thanks, Brian! If you can still be bothered, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65243789/using-newtonsoft-json-how-can-i-use-a-serializationbinder-and-customresolver-to) new question, built upon your latest fiddle.

Comment: No problem.  I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65244420/10263) to your new question.